# validate parts of the incoming web service request lazily in JAX-WS RI

Tags: java, web-services, validation, xsd, lazy-evaluation

I have to process big requests in a Java 8 web service (JAX-WS RI). A request contains a "header" and many "records" like this (not that 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th student records are invalid according to the schema):

```xml
<helloStudentsServiceRequest>
    <workshop>
        <name>wsname</name>
        <tutor>tutorname</tutor>
    </workshop>
    <studentList>
        <!--1 or more repetitions: -->
        <student>
            <Name>st1</Name>
            <Birth>1999-11-11</Birth>
        </student>
        <student>
            <Name>st2</Name>
        </student>
        <student>
            <Name>st2</Name>
            <Birth>199O-11-11</Birth>
        </student>
        <student>
            <Name>st3</Name>
            <Birth>stoneage</Birth>
        </student>
        <student>
            <Birth>stoneage</Birth>
        </student>
        <student>
            <Name>st6</Name>
            <Birth>2001-11-12</Birth>
        </student>
    </studentList>
</helloStudentsServiceRequest>
```

I use a schema (XSD) for describing my interface. For example:

```xml
<xsd:complexType name="HelloStudentsServiceRequestType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="workshop" type="WorkshopType" />
        <xsd:element name="studentList">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="student" type="StudentType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="WorkshopType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="tutor" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="StudentType">
</xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Name" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="Birth" type="xsd:date" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

I'd like to use this schema for validating the request.

However I am not allowed to reject a request if a few "record" in it is not valid according to the schema. In that case I have to process the valid records and return some meaningful information (preferably the SAX error) regarding the invalid ones.

I'd like to keep the request's schema free from the technical details neccessary to fullfill this "lazy validation". For example **I don't want** to use a "big string" to hold the "record" and then validate that string against the schema. That would break the interface and would be difficult to communicate to the clients. So this is **no-go** for me:

```xml
...
<xsd:element name="studentList">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="student" type="xsd:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
...
```

Do you know an elegant way to solve this in JAX-WS RI (JAXB2) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to customize JAXB bindings to map part of the XML to DOM. For details:

https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Avoid_strong_databinding.html#Mapping_to_DOM

So I mapped "WorkshopType" and "StudentType" to DOM. Now it's possible to validate those DOMs **individually** and reject or partially process the incoming message. It's also possible to catch the SAX exception if a DOM validating is not successful and signal that back to the client.

### [working example zipped](http://peter.risko.hu/java_incubator/ws_cf_inner_xmls_late_check.zip)

I used this binding customization:

```xml
<jxb:bindings version="1.0" 
xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<jxb:bindings
    schemaLocation="WorkshopType.xsd"
    node="//xsd:complexType[@name='WorkshopType']">
    <jxb:dom />
</jxb:bindings> 
<jxb:bindings
    schemaLocation="StudentType.xsd"
    node="//xsd:complexType[@name='StudentType']">
    <jxb:dom />
</jxb:bindings>
```

And these are the schemas:

For the request:

```xml
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="helloStudentsNS"
xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" jaxb:version="2.0"
targetNamespace="helloStudentsNS">

<xsd:include schemaLocation="StudentType.xsd" />
<xsd:include schemaLocation="WorkshopType.xsd" />

<xsd:element name="helloStudentsServiceRequest" type="HelloStudentsServiceRequestType" />
<xsd:element name="helloStudentsServiceResponse" type="HelloStudentsServiceResponseType" />

<xsd:complexType name="HelloStudentsServiceRequestType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="workshop" type="WorkshopType" />
        <xsd:element name="studentList">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="student" type="StudentType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="HelloStudentsServiceResponseType">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="GreetingHeader" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="StudentGreeting" type="xsd:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

For the workshop and student types:

```xml
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
elementFormDefault="qualified" 
xmlns="helloStudentsNS"
xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" 
jaxb:version="2.0"
targetNamespace="helloStudentsNS">

<xsd:element name="workshop" type="WorkshopType"/>

<xsd:complexType name="WorkshopType">
    <!-- <xsd:annotation><xsd:appinfo><jaxb:dom/></xsd:appinfo></xsd:annotation> -->
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="tutor" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

```xml
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
elementFormDefault="qualified" 
xmlns="helloStudentsNS" 
xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
jaxb:version="2.0" targetNamespace="helloStudentsNS">

<!-- 
-->
<xsd:element name="student" type="StudentType"/> 

<xsd:complexType name="StudentType">
    <!-- <xsd:annotation><xsd:appinfo><jaxb:dom/></xsd:appinfo></xsd:annotation> -->
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Name" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="Birth" type="xsd:date" />
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

And this is the java code:

```java
public HelloStudentsServiceResponseType greetStudents(HelloStudentsServiceRequestType req) {

    WorkshopType ws;
    // unmarshall workshop data
    Element element = req.getWorkshop(); // workshop is retrieved as DOM 
    try {
        Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller(); // jaxb ri unmarshaller not thread safe: https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Performance_and_thread_safety.html
        u.setSchema(workshopSchema); // enable validation by workshopType.xsd
        ws = u.unmarshal(element, WorkshopType.class).getValue(); // unmarshal
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        // this is fatal
        throw new RuntimeException("fatal: invalid workshop data: ", e);
    }

    // unmarshall students
    List<String> studentGreetings = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Element studentElement : req.getStudentList().getStudent()) { // retrieve students as DOMs
        try {
            StudentType st;
            Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller(); // jaxb ri unmarshaller not thread safe: https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Performance_and_thread_safety.html
            u.setSchema(studentSchema); // enable validation by studentType.xsd
            st = u.unmarshal(studentElement, StudentType.class).getValue();
            studentGreetings.add("Dear " + st.getName() + ", " + st.getBirth() + ", welcome in the workshop!");
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            Throwable cause = e.getLinkedException();
            if(cause != null) {
                studentGreetings.add("Dear student, your data is invalid: " + cause.getMessage());
            }
            else {
                studentGreetings.add("Dear student, there's an unknown problem with your data");
            }
        }
    }

    // construct response
    HelloStudentsServiceResponseType response = new HelloStudentsServiceResponseType();
    response.setGreetingHeader("I'd like to greet everybody in the " + ws.getName() + " workshop. " +
            "Your tutor is " + ws.getTutor());
    response.getStudentGreeting().addAll(studentGreetings);

    return response;
}
```